# When exactly do overwritten variables get garbage collected?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

When overwriting variables during some iterative task, when exactly does the variable get garbage collected? For example let's say we have a memory intensive function, `some_function()`. This function also returns a large object, `data`.

```py
def some_function(x):
    ...
    return data
```

If this function is getting called during some iterative task, e.g.

```py
for x in some_iterable:
    output = some_function(x)
```

Does the new variable `output` get garbage collected as soon as `some_function()` is called? Or does it only free up memory when a new value is returned? I only care about the memory being freed in the kernel, not necessarily in the system (so I might be using the term garbage collection incorrectly).

Comment: It's not the variable that's being garbage collected. It's the value. And value would be garbage collected once there is nothing pointing to it.

Comment: @Nf4r So does the reference to the value get overwritten immediately or only once something is returned and assigned to the variable?

Comment: First the function is executed, the value is calculated and assigned to the `output` variable. At the second run the function is executed again, so there is another value and the previous value is lost because there is nothing pointing to it, so it's ready to be garbage collected, but it does not happen immediately AFAIK. I'm not an expert and didn't really dive deep into python garbage collector but I would expect it being more like periodic "task". But I might be wrong here.

Comment: "I only care about the memory being freed in the kernel" - is not a Python garbage collection question, but rather a virtual memory replacement question - see my answer below.

Comment: Read the documentation for the [`object.__del__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method closely and you will note that there's no guarantee that no-longer-referenced values will _ever_ be garbage-collected. Python is not C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data is no longer reachable the Python garbage collector, in the background, marks the memory as being available for subsequent allocations. It doesn't get freed with respect to the kernel, however.

If what you care about is when the physical memory is made available to other processes by the kernel, that's another thing: the memory is still virtually mapped into your Python process' address space, so in order for that physical memory to be freed by the kernel, either your Python process has to exit (thus freeing all of the physical memory allocated to it), or the physical memory formerly holding your data needs to become *least recently used* according to the kernel's virtual memory policy. If there are no other processes competing for it (likely in a multi-gigabyte system), that could take a long time. If there are other processes competing for physical memory, it could happen in a number of seconds or minutes.  Further, if your Python process allocates any more data, all of a sudden those pages are recently used again, so become last-in-line for physical reclamation. If you're that low on physical memory, though, your system is probably having other issues.

Comment: "if your Python process allocates any more data, all of a sudden those pages are recently used again" Why would allocating a new page of memory have an influence over all the other pages of the process? I could see them being preferred because they're part of an active process, but a page that hasn't been touched in a day would surely not be paged in again just because another page was asked for?

Comment: When Python allocates more data it is likely to be allocated from the recently garbage-collected region. It's not obvious, but a process's virtual memory space never (usually) shrinks - so new allocations either grow the address space, or come from recently free'd memory.

Comment: Yeah giving memory back is rather complicated with the given Kernel APIs so I'd not expect Python to ever do so. Sure if the process accesses an old "freed" (in Python) page again it'll be hot, I just interpreted your sentence differently.